# reliableSession enabled="true" in Service or client sie?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have created service which uses nettcpip binding.I want check session id of client and server.According to my knowledge by default reliable sessions are not enabled.That's why I am getting different value.I want to enable reliable sessions so I can I same session id for client and server.In which config file I have to do that setting service or client?

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTCP">
      <reliableSession enabled="true"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: NetTcpBinding is by default reliable binding. In other non-reliable bindings,you have to set  <bindings> tag on the both side.